# custom labels on google's geochart

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to use custom labels on google's geochart Markers? (similar to infowindows in google maps)

For example, most points on a map are given with ['city', 'population'] such as

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',  'Population', 'Area'],
    ['Rome',     2761477,    1285.31],
    ['Milan',    1324110,    181.76],.....
```

Is it possible to use a custom string instead of population or area? For example, if I feed in this array

```
 <?php $city = array(array('City','Info'), array('Pittsburgh','Boring'), array('Los Angeles','Awesome!'), array('Chicago','Better than Cleveland'));  ?>
```

Can I use a string for a description or do I have to use a list of pre-set options?

btw, to display this just use this.

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

  <?php echo json_encode($city); ?> 
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.
Check out some examples:

http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/

You should need to had the data in this format, for example:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country'); // Implicit domain label col.
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'}); // 

data.addRows([[{v:"Olympia  Washington",f:"Olympia"},1,"Capital city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Seattle Washington",f:"Seattle"},2,"Largest city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Spokane  Washington",f:"Spokane"},3,"Seconde Largest city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Vancouver  Washington",f:"Vancouver"},4,"Fourth largest city of the state of Washington"],]);
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers